# what should be the mongodb update shell command

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

this is one of my document in a collection

```
{   
    "_id": ObjectId("55e86e98f493590878bb45d7"),
    "KIDS_M_0_2" : "",
    "KIDS_F_0_2" : "",
    "KIDS_U_0_2" : "Y",
    "KIDS_M_3_5" : "",
    "KIDS_F_3_5" : "",
    "KIDS_U_3_5" : "Y",
    "KIDS_M_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_F_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_U_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_M_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_F_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_U_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_M_16_17" : "",
    "KIDS_F_16_17" : "",
    "KIDS_U_16_17" : "Y"
}
```

I want this to be like

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("55e86e98f493590878bb45d7"),
    "KIDS": { "KIDS_M_0_2" : "",
    "KIDS_F_0_2" : "",
    "KIDS_U_0_2" : "Y",
    "KIDS_M_3_5" : "",
    "KIDS_F_3_5" : "",
    "KIDS_U_3_5" : "Y",
    "KIDS_M_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_F_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_U_6_10" : "",
    "KIDS_M_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_F_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_U_11_15" : "",
    "KIDS_M_16_17" : "",
    "KIDS_F_16_17" : "",
    "KIDS_U_16_17" : "Y"
}
```

Can this be done via shell, What should be my update command. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need more than simple command.

You need to loop over  the cursor returns by the [`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) method using the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method then create  a new object "kids" using the fields' name and their value. The next thing to do is [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset) all the fields and use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator to create the new field. Of course you to do this you use ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)<sup>1</sup> operations for maximum efficiency.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0; 

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var kids = {}; 
    for(key in doc) {
        if(key != '_id' && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(doc, key)) {
            kids[key] = doc[key];
            var unset = {};         
            unset[key] = '';         
            bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( { '$unset': unset } );
            count++;    
        }        
        bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne({ '$set': { 'KIDS': kids } } ); 
        if (count % 500 === 0) {
            bulk.execute();     
            bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        }
})

if (count > 0)  
    bulk.execute()
```

After this operation your documents look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567d99bcbc08a0817a1b06dd"),
        "KIDS" : {
                "KIDS_M_0_2" : "",
                "KIDS_F_0_2" : "",
                "KIDS_U_0_2" : "Y",
                "KIDS_M_3_5" : "",
                "KIDS_F_3_5" : "",
                "KIDS_U_3_5" : "Y",
                "KIDS_M_6_10" : "",
                "KIDS_F_6_10" : "",
                "KIDS_U_6_10" : "",
                "KIDS_M_11_15" : "",
                "KIDS_F_11_15" : "",
                "KIDS_U_11_15" : "",
                "KIDS_M_16_17" : "",
                "KIDS_F_16_17" : "",
                "KIDS_U_16_17" : "Y"
        }
}
```

---

MongoDB 3.2 [deprecates](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) `Bulk()` and its associated methods and provides the [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method.

```js
var operations = [];

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var kids = {}; 
    for(var key in doc) { 
        if(!key.startsWith('_id') && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(doc, key)) { 
            kids[key] = doc[key];
            var unset = {};
            unset[key] = ''; 
            operations.push(
                { 'updateOne': 
                    { 
                        'filter': { '_id': doc._id } ,         
                        'update': { '$unset': unset } 
                    }             
                }         
            );    
        }     
        operations.push(         
            { 'updateOne':              
                { 
                    'filter': { '_id': doc._id } ,              
                    'update': { '$set': { 'KIDS': kids } } 
                }         
            }     
        ); 
    } 
    operations.push( { 'ordered': true } ); 
})

db.collection.bulkWrite(operations)
```

---

<sup>1.The [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API is new in version 2.6. So you should consider to upgrade if you are on older version</sup>